# Annoying "error in process filter: Overlapping strings detected"

Tags: python, elpy

When editing python code with elpy, if I type a single or double quote while writing a new line of code (i.e. adding or changing a line in existing code), the UI freezes momentarily, make the bell sound, and the minibuffer shows "error in process filter: Overlapping strings detected".  It's extremely annoying and unhelpful.  What can I do (besides disabling elpy)?

EDIT: Additional details:

- disabling elpy-mode makes it stop
- doesn't seem to happen with small files (e.g. 62 lines), but does happen with larger files (e.g. 524 lines)
- elpy version 1.34.0

EDIT (by NickD): I was able to reproduce this independently. The backtrace I got is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (cl-assertion-failed ((>= string-start last-string-end) "Overlapping strings detected (start=%d, last-end=%..." 12628 12629))
  cl--assertion-failed((>= string-start last-string-end) "Overlapping strings detected (start=%d, last-end=%..." (12628 12629) nil)
  python-nav-end-of-statement()
  python-nav-end-of-defun()
  python-info-current-defun()
  #f(compiled-function (info) #<bytecode -0xf329f5f70555bd7>)(nil)
  elpy-promise-resolve([*elpy-promise* #f(compiled-function (info) #<bytecode -0xf329f5f70555bd7>) elpy-rpc--default-error-callback #<buffer models.py> nil] nil)
  elpy-rpc--handle-json(((result) (id . 8)))
  elpy-rpc--filter(#<process  *elpy-rpc [project:/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ environment:/usr]*<1>> "{\"result\": null, \"id\": 8}\n")
```

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce. Maybe start with `emacs -q` plus a small init file for `elpy` and see if it goes away? If it does, bisect your init file to figure out what's causing the problem

Comment: The file needs to have some size - it doesn't happen with small files.  I'll try your suggestion though.

Comment: You should add this (and any other pertinent) information to your question (comments might  disappear). In particular, how big the file has to be before you see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! It turns out I can reproduce that. I'll add the backtrace I get to your question. Maybe you can open a bug report with elpy?

Comment: There's a closed issue already, so apparently it's been fixed: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1381

Comment: Thanks for digging that up! The issue describes a workaround for elpy, but mentions that the bug is in `python.el` - we'll have to wait and see how that gets resolved.

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround suggested in https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1381#issuecomment-434313600

Adding `(setq elpy-eldoc-show-current-function nil)` to my emacs init file makes it stop happening for me.  Good enough!